# Why PostgreSQL do whole scan on index when condition is FALSE?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I notice some slow down when query is running. From 5ms to 200ms. (+44ms JIT)

https://explain.depesz.com/s/lZYf#l12
[similar](https://explain.depesz.com/s/leH3), but JIT is off

[image]

Underlined expression is `NULL` so whole `filter` expression is `FALSE`.

Why here PG waste time 227ms? What I did wrong?

```sql
EXPLAIN( ANALYSE, FORMAT JSON, VERBOSE, settings, buffers )
WITH
_app_period AS ( select ?::tstzrange ),
ready AS (
SELECT

  min( lower( o.app_period ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY agreement_id ) <@ (select * from _app_period) AS new_order,
  max( upper( o.app_period ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY agreement_id ) <@ (select * from _app_period) AS del_order
  ,o.*
FROM "order_bt" o
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Usage',   (select * from _app_period), o ) acc_u   ON acc_u.ready
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Invoice', (select * from _app_period), o ) acc_i   ON acc_i.ready


LEFT JOIN agreement a   ON a.id     = o.agreement_id
LEFT JOIN xcheck    c   ON c.doc_id = o.id and c.doctype = 'OrderDetail'

WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  o.app_period && app_period()
)
SELECT * FROM ready
```

**UPD**
Server version is 13.1

**Is the second execution faster?**
No. Result is reproducible all the time.

**Perhaps sys_time() is expensive - what is that function?**
This is stable function which do `select coalesce( biconf( 'sys_time' )::timestamptz, now() )`. `app_period()` is `STABLE SQL` and do similar thing.

**Are you sure that the expression is NULL for all rows?**
Yes. I check result of `app_period()` it is `NULL`, so it does not matter how many rows in table. `o.app_period && NULL` will result `NULL` for all rows.

**Does the execution time change if you replace the expression with a literal NULL?**
Yes, changing condition to `WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  o.app_period && NULL` reduce time to [0.08ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/OyyW). Plan is changed.

**Do you have indexes on o.sys_period and o.app_period?**
Yes. I have: `"order_id_sys_period_app_period_excl" EXCLUDE USING gist (id WITH =, sys_period WITH &&, app_period WITH &&)`

**And what happens when you execute the query without the CTE?**
Without `CTE` many things are inlined and time is reduced to [0.5ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/0ByF#l6). But for IndexScan similar condition is used (now it is fast)

---

When I put `(select * from _app_period)` everywhere then query also run fast: [15ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/kDCJ3#l13). `Filter` is planned as `$3`: `(o.app_period && $3) AND (o.sys_period @> sys_time())`

Comment: The index could be bloated or contain dead tuples. Is the second execution faster? Perhaps `sys_time()` is expensive - what is that function? Are you sure that the expression is NULL for all rows? Does the execution time change if you replace the expression with a literal NULL?

Comment: Do you have indexes on o.sys_period and o.app_period? And what happens when you execute the query without the CTE? Because you can run this query perfectly without using a CTE

Comment: And something else, do you need all the left joins when you don't use the data from these relations in this query?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: yes, I need, because in real life application I use those result. Here `LEFT JOIN` are left because they influence query execution speed. In short I will answer other your questions.

Comment: @FrankHeikens See updates

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: See updates

Comment: Then it is clear: it must be the filter condition. Remove it in bits and pieces until you find out which part is the expensive one.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: How to remove? this long condition come from function. The result of this expression is `NULL`. Why PG does not see that it is evaluated to FALSE and to full scan (over 20814 records and filter out them all)?

Comment: Reduce it by bits. For example, replace the `app_time()` call with a constant and see if that makes a difference. Remove the `ELSE` branch and see if that makes a difference. And so on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: The functions are stable, I suppose PG call them once and reuse these values for each row. So fillter condition will look like: `(o.app_period && NULL) AND (o.sys_period @> '2020-03-04 03:33:18)`. Compare prelast and last examples: [0.5ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/0ByF#l6) and [15ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/kDCJ3#l13) Functions are same, but when planner inline it - it works slower by 30 times!

Comment: Don't suppose anything, experiment. I cannot do it, as I am not on your database.

Comment: How can the result of app_period() be NULL if it is similar to sys_time(), which clearly can't return NULL?

Comment: @jjanes: similar is not same. app_period() also do some checks and return value.